# Variational computations using the moving frame

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I'm attempting to learn how to do variational calculus using the method of moving frames, similar to Robert Bryant's answer found here:

[Variation of curvature with respect to immersion?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182757/variation-of-curvature-with-respect-to-immersion)

To that end, I have been looking for a reference that has some explanation or maybe some examples - does anyone know a book/article offhand?

Thanks a lot,